# unable to draw regions in ipython notebook

Tags: real-analysis

I try to draw the 4 regions of the plane $(t,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by these inequalities:

$t \le 0 \\
\\ t > 0, y < 0
\\  t > 0, 0 \le y \le t^2
\\  t > 0, t^2 < y
$

What I did:

This is the snap code I tried to run from plot.ly:

```
%pylab inline
from plotly import *
from plotly.offline import *
init_notebook_mode()

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.sin(x), label='sin'); ax.plot(np.cos(x), label='cos')

update = {'data':[{'fill': 'tozeroy'}]}  # this updates BOTH traces now
plot_url = py.plot_mpl(fig, update=update, filename='mpl-multi-fill')
```

plot.ly but requires some authentication as I have the following error:

*Aw, snap! We don't have an account for ''. Want to try again? You can authenticate with your email address or username. Sign in is not case sensitive.
Don't have an account? plot.ly
Questions? accounts@plot.ly*

Could you please help? 
Are there any built-in tools to draw regions in ipython?
Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to use the offline mode. With these, the plotly is working fine for me:

```
%pylab inline
from plotly import *
from plotly.offline import *
init_notebook_mode()
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, I updated the initial post with your code

Comment: @PerelMan Your code is just plotting a sine and a cosine function on the domain $[0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: @PerelMan I think you'd like to do something like this: https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-plots/

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now. you were right. I can now have an offline area

Comment: Do you know if we can plot inequalities like t<=0 using plotly ?

Comment: @PerelMan I'm a begginer also. But I'm not sure if you can plot the whole $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $t \leq 0$. But I'm sure you would be able to get better and more help on the stackoverflow site.